# Scroller in DataGridView changes LargeChange and Maximum values

Tags: c#, winforms, user-interface, datagridview

I'm trying to implement Excel-like behavior of my DataGridView. For this purpose I made own class:

```
class CustomDataGridView : DataGridView
```

And in the constructor I set the values of HorizontalScrollBar's properties SmallChange, LargeChange and Maximum to the values I need. But after application started I see in the debugger that these values changed somehow somewhere. Has anyone ever met such things before? Is any possibility to manage this situation?

Comment: Visual Studio’s [conditional breakpoints](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/08/18/debugging-tips-with-visual-studio-2010.aspx) allow you to break in the debugger only if some specific condition that you specify is met. Set breakpoint to break when properties have changed.

Comment: If I not mistaken conditional breakpoints are possible only in the code that I have access to (so generally it's my own code). I can do this somewhere in my code but it will be postfactum knowledge about property value change. It will not show me the real place where it was changed.

Comment: If you override `OnHandleCreated` you'll see these properties changed just there in the base class implementation but I don't know why. I recommend using Reflector.